# jQuery sticky div misbehaving

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bit of code to keep a sidebar element in view (and within the bounds of its parent) while scrolling and am having a bit of a problem. I have multiple articles on a page (approximately 10), each with it's own sidebar. The markup looks like this:

```
<article>
    <section class="project-details entry-content">
        <header>
            ...
        </header>
    </section>
    <section class="offset-by-four twelve columns">
        ...
    </section>
</article>
```

And the CSS:

```
article {
    padding-top: 2em;
    position: relative; }
article .project-details {
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px; }
```

... and finally, the Javascript:

```
$.fn.persistent = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({
        duration: 0,
        lockBottom: true
    },
    options),
    elements = [];

    this.each(function() {
        var parentPaddingTop = parseInt($(this).parent().css('paddingTop'));
        $(this).data({
            'parentPaddingTop': parentPaddingTop,
            'startOffset': $(this).parent().offset().top
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute'
        });
        if (opts.lockBottom) {
            var bottomPos = $(this).parent().height() - $(this).height() + parentPaddingTop;
            if (bottomPos < 0) {
                bottomPos = 0;
            }
            $(this).data('bottomPos', bottomPos);
        }
        elements.push($(this));
    });
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var pastStartOffset = $(document).scrollTop() > opts.startOffset;
        $.each(elements,
            function() {
                var parentPaddingTop = $(this).data('parentPaddingTop'),
                    startOffset = $(this).data('startOffset'),
                    bottomPos = $(this).data('bottomPos');
                $(this).stop();
                var objFartherThanTopPos = $(this).offset().top > startOffset,
                    objBiggerThanWindow = $(this).outerHeight() < $(window).height();
                if ((pastStartOffset || objFartherThanTopPos) && objBiggerThanWindow) {
                    var newpos = ($(document).scrollTop() - startOffset + parentPaddingTop);
                    if (newpos > bottomPos) {
                        newpos = bottomPos;
                    }
                    if ($(document).scrollTop() < startOffset) {
                        newpos = parentPaddingTop;
                    }
                    $(this).animate({
                        top: newpos
                    }, opts.duration);
                }
            }
        );
    });
};
```

It's the `.project-details` DIV that should remain sticky, but for some reason only the first one on the page works and the rest do nothing. Occasionally the second will start to work while scrolling down the page and then will fail about halfway through.

Can anyone see any glaring flaws with this code that might cause such behavior?

Comment: http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/sticky-elements/ .. you don't need to re do it from scratch... save yourself some time ...

Comment: or try `return  $.each(elements,....` and `return this.each....` as they maintain the chain-ability ...

Comment: Waypoints seems like it may be a bit much for my needs? Also, when adding `return ` to the script none of them work.

Comment: thats because $(window).scroll has not executed itself because you returning this.each you understand?

Comment: I understand that the returns are in essence stopping the script before it reaches the scroll event. So why do I need the returns?

Comment: forget about returns, `this.each(function() {` should be `this.each(function(i,n) {`  and every `this` inside that function should be `n` follow my question ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the following code and make sure you understand that `n` is each element, using this instead a each function does not refer to the current element if that makes sense.

```
 this.each(function(i,n) {
        var parentPaddingTop = parseInt($(n).parent().css('paddingTop'));
        $(n).data({
            'parentPaddingTop': parentPaddingTop,
            'startOffset': $(n).parent().offset().top
        }).css({
            position: 'absolute'
        });
        if (opts.lockBottom) {
            var bottomPos = $(n).parent().height() - $(n).height() + parentPaddingTop;
            if (bottomPos < 0) {
                bottomPos = 0;
            }
            $(n).data('bottomPos', bottomPos);
        }
        elements.push($(n));
    });
```